# Response URL has a backslash in Laravel 8

Tags: file-upload, laravel-8

I have this code that returns the array of images with the link, but the problem is it has a backslash in my URL return.

```
public function getImagesAttribute(): array
{
    return [
        'thumbnail' => $this->getImagePath('thumbnail'),
        'large' => $this->getImagePath('large'),
        'original' => $this->getImagePath('original'),
    ];
}

protected function getImagePath($size): string
{
    return Storage::disk('public')->url("uploads/user-account/${size}/" . 
        $this->file_name);
}
```

Here's the result:
[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blj6k.png]

Comment: That's just how `/`'s are represented in JSON. Does your code actually break? Are you getting some kind of error with this code?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, My code is not broken, the problem I have when I'm going to request a data from the server, the return data with the image URL has a '\/' symbol. And also every request that has a '/' it will return '\/'.

Comment: Yes, because once again, that is how a `/` is represented in JSON: https://3v4l.org/emjPW. I will ask again, what, specifically, doesn't work with your code?

Comment: Ah okay, I got it so meaning if the return has a '/' symbol then it will override by the JSON response and add backslash. I guess I have a miscalculation about the getImagePath function. I will try to json_decode it. Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think that's got anything to do with the `getImagePath()` function, i.e. if you did `dd(Storage::disk('public')->url("uploads/user-account/{$size}/" . $this->file_name));` instead of `return ...`, you wouldn't see those `\/`'s. What is the source of that screenshot?

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blj6k.png) This is the issue that I have. And it is still not working. 
I am using echo to display a URL the `\/` will not show up but in response to the API request, it will display. Sorry for my bad explaination.

Comment: I mean what is the code that generates that screenshot... None of the code you posted will output what is in that screenshot directly.

Comment: When I dd it will not show the symbol but in API response I will shown up.

Comment: Also, of course `\/` will be in the API request, as data is typically sent via JSON. You need to decode it on the other end, which is generally done by default by most JavaScript applications.

Comment: Ah okay, I ready done that one of the frontend sides but I'm also working on the backend side. That's all, Thanks @TimLewis I appreciate you :)

Comment: Ok, no problem! I would consider deleting this question if you don't need an answer, but either way, happy to help 